# Akka scala-io ask and wait for respone

Tags: scala, sockets, akka

I'm using scala-io in my akka actors, in my case I need to send request and wait for response, in official docs (http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/io-tcp.html) I can see the answer is asynchronous.

How can I wait for response, can I use somehow ? (ask) pattern

```
class SocketClient(remoteAddress: InetSocketAddress, listener: ActorRef) extends Actor {

  import Tcp._
  import context.system

  IO(Tcp) ! Connect(remoteAddress)

  def receive = {

    case CommandFailed(_: Connect) =>
      listener ! ConnectFailure
      context stop self

    case Connected(remote, local) =>
      listener ! ConnectSuccess

      val connection = sender
      connection ! Register(self)

      context become {

        case data: ByteString =>
          connection ! Write(data)

        case CommandFailed(w: Write) =>
          Logger.error(s"Error during writing")

        case Received(data) =>
          listener ! data

        case Disconnect =>
          connection ! Close

        case _: ConnectionClosed =>
          Logger.error(s"Connection has been closed ${remoteAddress.getAddress}")
          context stop self
      }
  }
}
```

Can I use something like:

```
connection ? Write(data)
```

Answer (score 4):

Yes, but you should take in account the fact that ask-pattern allows you to receive only first reply from actor.

In your case it's `connection`, which may reply some additional or even unrelated objects (it depends on back-pressure/acknowledgement mode you choose. For example, if you use `Write` - you may receive the written (to the socket) object's acknowledge instead of response.

You can avoid it by:

- using NoAck as an AckEvent (see http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/io-tcp.html, Throttling Reads and Writes section).
- use atomic requests/replies (no multi-part)
- use one actor per protocol (per each "ping-pong" sequence)

In other words, ask pattern just creates own internal actor per message and make it a sender, so all replies (for this particular message)  are going to this micro-actor. When it receives first reply - future (returned by `?`) becomes completed - and internal actor destroyed (so other replies will be ignored).

Also, `connection` automatically replies to registered (by `Register` message) listener instead of sender - so you should create mediate actor:

```
class Asker(connection: ActorRef) extends Actor {
   import Tcp._
   connection ! Register(self); 
   def receive = {
        case x => 
          val parent = sender()
          connection ! x
          context become {case x => parent ! x; context.unbecome()} 
   }   
}

trait TcpAskSupport {
   self: Actor => 

   def asker(connection: ActorRef) = 
      context.child(connection.path.name + "Asker")
        .getOrElse(system.actorOf(Props(classOf[Asker], connection), 
           connection.path.name + "Asker"))
}
```

Usage example:

```
class Client extends Actor with TcpAskSupport {

  import Tcp._
  import context.system

  IO(Tcp) ! Connect(new InetSocketAddress("61.91.16.168", 80))
  implicit val timeout = Timeout(new FiniteDuration(5, SECONDS))

  def receive = {
    case CommandFailed(_: Connect) =>
      println("connect failed")
      context stop self

    case c @ Connected(remote, local) =>
      println("Connected" + c)
      val connection = sender()
      asker(connection) ? Write(ByteString("GET /\n", "UTF-8"), NoAck) onComplete {
          case x => println("Response" + x)
      } 
    case x => println("[ERROR] Received" + x)    
  }
}
```

Comment: When I'm using: `connection ? Write(data, NoAck)` it doesn't return anything just waiting, but also I'm receiving `Received(data)` with text response

Comment: This will not work for multiple fast writes, second Write will be used as a response

Comment: As i said in the start - you can use ask pattern only for atomic requests/resposes. If you mean that you want to send second message after receiving response - you can do it inside onComplete.

Comment: No, I have a multiple request for example single request data->response AND background ping->pong for keeping connection

Comment: it's a special case - you may implement keep-alive inside Asker, and process pong messages separately (also inside Asker)

Comment: in general case if you have a complex protocol - you should correlate messages for each subprotocol and route them inside Asker (and use one client actor per subprotocol). P.S. you need it only if all subprotocols should be inside one connection